# Two separate ways to link a css file to multiple php files in same directory

Tags: php, html, css, stylesheet

I have multiple php files in the same directory.

Then I have one css file in the following directory: style/css/fileName.css

All of my php files in that directory link to the stylesheet through the following code:

```
<link href="style/css/fileName.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Except one file for some reason the styling will not be applied except when I add "/" behind the style to look as the following:

```
<link href="/style/css/fileName.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Why is this the case? They are both in the same exact directory.

EDIT: All of the files I am discussing ARE at the same index level. Just this one file requires "/"..if both of the above links are correct for the index level. Then why is it that this one file without having "/" before the style/css/fileName.css stops it from being styled?

Comment: Do either of the PHP files contain the `<base>` HTML tag?

Comment: @Jonathan None have the <base> HTML tag

Comment: why dont you use same style method in those page?

Comment: @saleemnfs that is the point...If I use this <link href="style/css/fileName.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> in the one PHP file the styling will not be applied. So I can't use the same style method.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a variable which contains your base url in your main configuration file and just do something like this:

`$base_url = 'http://mysite';`

And then you just do

`<link href="<?= $base_url; ?>/style/css/fileName.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`

Or basically an absolute path. Have you considered that option?

I think like that there wouldn't be an issue with the location of the file.

Comment: And you can also easily edit the `$base_url` variable

Answer (score -1):

Adding "/" at the beginning of a path means "start from the root of the site." Leaving off that initial slash means "start from where we are right now."

If your php files are at the root of your site, such as `http://localhost/index.php`, then `href="/style/css/fileName.css"` and `href="style/css/fileName.css"` ultimately point to the same place, which is `http://localhost/style/css/fileName.css`

If your php files and other directories are not at the root level (for example, in a directory called "directory", like this: `http://localhost/directory/index.php`), then using `href="style/css/fileName.css"` in that php file is equivalent to `href="http://localhost/directory/style/css/fileName.css"`

**My guess is that your PHP file is not at the root level**, which is why the presence of the leading slash in your CSS file's path breaks things. If you do want to start your path to your CSS file with a slash (which you probably should do, so that you don't have to add a different path to your CSS in every PHP file, depending on where it is in your directory structure) then you just need to make sure that you have identified the correct path from the root level to your CSS.